# Trouble serving Rails 3 app with nginx + unicorn on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, amazon-ec2, unicorn

When I point my browser to "rails_app.com", I can view rails_app/public/index.html on the EC2 instance, but when I delete rails_app/public/index.html I get the nginx 403 error,

```
      directory index of "/home/www-data/rails_app/public/" is forbidden,
```

instead of being able to see my Rails 3.0.3 rails_app.  I'm using

```
Nginx Version 0.8.54
Unicorn_rails Version 3.4.0
```

One post I read said that I need to make sure that the correct version of ruby is available for user www-data, which I did.  I have the directory owners for the rails_app set for user and group to www-data, and the permissions set to 775.   I can see that the HTTP requests are reaching nginx by looking at the access log. I have DNS setup for my domain name, "rails_app.com" to point to an AWS Elastic IP address which is the Elastic IP of the EC2 instance that I am running nginx + unicorn with my rails app on.

**I think I solved this 403 error above as described in Update 2 below.  Now I get a 500 error.  I fixed the 500 error, as described in Update 4 below.**

I am runnng nginx with

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/nginx.conf
```

and I am running unicorn with

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8000 -E production -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

Here is my unicorn.rb:

```
worker_processes 1
preload_app true
main_dir = '/home/www-data/rails_app'
working_directory '/home/www-data/rails_app'
listen 8000, :tcp_nopush => true
listen "/tmp/shop.socket", :backlog => 2048
timeout 30
user 'www-data'
shared_path = "#{main_dir}/shared"
pid "#{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

**UPDATE 1 -**  I simplified my nginx.conf, after reading this [link](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) on Nginx Pitfalls.
Here is my nginx.conf:

**UPDATE 2 -** This [post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2437227), said that having $uri/ in try_files causes the 403 error, because nginx can't list the directory.  So I removed $uri/ from try_files and now I get a 500 error, with nothing showing up in the nginx or unicorn error logs.  Any ideas how to debug this?

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes 2;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
  accept_mutex on;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile    on;

  tcp_nopush  on;
  tcp_nodelay off;

  keepalive_timeout   65;
  client_body_timeout 120;
  upstream app_server {
 #   server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/shop.socket fail_timeout=0;
  } 

  log_format main '\$remote_addr - \$remote_user [\$time_local] \$request '
                  '"\$status" \$body_bytes_sent "\$http_referer" '
                  '"\$http_user_agent" "\$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80 ;
    server_name rails_app.com *.rails_app.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root /home/www-data/rails_app/public;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location /    {
      try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }

    location @app    {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;

    }   # location /

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /home/www-data/rails_app/public;
    }

 }  # server

}   # http
```

Using a TCP port for unicorn, I can see that unicorn is listening using

```
netstat -natp
```

Now the error I get is the 500.html page displayed:

```
   We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

There are no errors in the nginx error logfile or in the unicorn error log file.

**Update 3 -**

As I dig into this more, I think the problem might be with unicorn.  When I run the rails app at this [example](http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/), it works fine, but that rails app is using sqlite3 instead of mysql.  Also this example allows for zero downtime deployment, by using the before_fork and after_fork code here:

```
 before_fork do |server, worker|
   defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
 end

 after_fork do |server, worker|
   defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
 end
```

When I try to run my rails_app with mysql and using the before_fork, after_fork code above in my unicorn.rb file, it fails and I get the error:

```
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:316:in `retrieve_connection': ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

**Update 4 -**

I added -d (debug) to the unicorn_rails command line as

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8000 -E production -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/unicorn.rb -d -D
```

and found a number of errors, the first being that config/application.rb was missing config.secret_token.  Added that and continue to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working.  The final problem was that Unicorn was complaining that there were no routes for "/".  Running 'bundle exec rake routes' produced nothing.  Once 'bundle exec rake routes' produced routes, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220636/rails-3-rake-routes-not-working-no-routes-shown-as-output), then the website came up.

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction.  In my case I removed "$uri/" from the try_files line and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that failing to set 'preload_app true' in your config file might trigger this.

Comment: dmw - What are you referring to by the pronoun -this- at the end of your sentence?  I did have preload_app true in my unicorn.rb config file when I included the before_fork and after_fork code, and I still got the ConnectionNotEstablished  error in connection_pool.rb.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. Since preload_app is true for you, clearly the problem has a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem.  I was actually able to go around it temporarily by running webrick from the app directory (`$ rails s`) and then hit my server at port 3000 (http://example.com:3000).

p.s. is the unicorn.log file supposed to loop/scroll without stopping? Seems odd to me when I'm not hitting the app.